# How do I get tagged users and how many times they appear in photos alongside the current user using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to create an FQL query that returns all users who appear together with the current user in all public photos. Here is what I'm having so far:

```
select uid from user where uid in (
    select subject from photo_tag where pid in (
        select pid from photo where pid in (
            select pid from photo_tag where subject=me()
        )
    )
) and uid in (
    select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()
)
```

This works, but I would like to also get the number of times these users show up in the photos alongside the current user. In theory, the following query should work:

```
select subject from photo_tag where pid in (
    select pid from photo where pid in (
         select pid from photo_tag where subject=me()
    )
) and subject in (
    select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()
)
```

But it always returns an empty dataset. Could I get some advice on where I'm going wrong so I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't requested 'friends_photos' permissions. Here is the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) and here is the [reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) that shows you how to request those permissions. I don't see any errors on your FQL, just not very optimal.